# Login redirection based on role php

Tags: php

i have a login database

```
username | password | role

xxxxxx     xxxxxxx    Admin
xxxxxx     xxxxxxx    Trainer
xxxxxx     xxxxxxx    Client
xxxxxx     xxxxxxx    Line Manager
```

is it possible on login that someone with Admin role redirects to admin.php someone with a Trainer role logs in to trainer.php someone with a Client role logs in to client.php.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly possible.

Comment: could you show me how to do it?

Comment: could you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have already retrieved the user info from the database, and stored their role into a Session variable, its as simple as this...

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $role = $_SESSION['role'];

 if($role=="Admin"){header("location: www.yourpage.com/admin.php");}
 elseif($role=="Trainer"){header("location: www.yourpage.com/trainer.php");}
 elseif($role=="Client"){header("location: www.yourpage.com/client.php");}
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the Role for the valid user and compare like this

```
 $Role  = query_database("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE username='".$_POST["username"]."'");


if ( $Role == "Admin")
 {
    header("location:www.example.com/admin.php");
 }
  else  if ( $Role == "Trainer ")
 {
          header("location: www.example.com/Trainer.php");
 }
```

Like this

Comment: how to i get the role for the valid user?

Comment: @user It's *your* database! How do log your user in without knowing how to get his information?

Comment: @user2612747 in SQL query get the role for the given username and compre it

Comment: Actually, I'd say your first line of code is misleading, because you just assign a string, especially considering you're also working with a string later on. Rather wrap something like that in an unspecified but talking function (name); something like `$role = query_database("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME...");`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

You can check the role from the db for the user, and then you can redirect with a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) or an [if](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) structure:

```
 switch ($role) {
     case 'admin':
         $_SESSION['role'] = 'admin';
         // redirect to admin
         header( 'Location: admin.php');
         break;
     case 'client':
         $_SESSION['role'] = 'client';
          // redirect to client
         header( 'Location: client.php');
         break;
      case 'trainer':
         $_SESSION['role'] = 'trainer';
          // redirect to admin
         header( 'Location: trainer.php');
         break; }
```

The [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) var allows you to check if the user who access admin.php, client.php or trainer.php is really an authentified administrator/client/trainer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just store the role -> home relationship and look it up, something like

```
<?php
function get_home_by_role($role)
{
    $home = 'admin.php';

    $roles = array(
        'client'    => 'client.php',
        'trainer'   => 'trainer.php',
    );

    if (isset($roles[$role])) {
        $home = $roles[$role];
    }

    return $home;
}
$user = get_user();
$home = get_home_by_role($user->role);
header("Location: http://example.org/$home");
exit;
```

Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this (but possibly using a database table to store role redirects to make it more dynamically):

```
$redirect = array(
    'Admin' => 'http://example.com/admin.php',
    'Trainer' => 'http://example.com/trainer.php',
    'Client' => 'http://example.com/client.php',
    //...
    );

if ($redir = @$redirect[$role]) {
    header('Location: ' . $redir);
    ob_end_clean(); // In case you've had output buffered already; optional.
    exit();
}
else
    die("Unknown role: $role; don't know where to go!");
```

Comment: You're mixing up your JS and PHP syntax there. ;) I tried editing, but apparently 1 char isn't enough of an edit.

Comment: The `@` on the `$redir` assignment? Yes, forgot the `$`, the `@` is intentional. :)

Comment: Whops... Fixed that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your login table is called `users`, you are already connected to your DB and the user is loading this page after filling some sort of login form:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_POST["username"]."'";

$result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

switch($row["role"])
{
    case "Admin":
       header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/admin.php");
       die();
       break;
    case "Trainer":
    //.....
}
```

Comment: You should use `Location` in the header of your HTTP response. Spitting out a random and standalone `meta` tag is not really something you should do and browsers might even ignore it considering it's malformed HTML if standalone. Also it will cause your browser to show the page at first; possibly even avoiding the redirect based on security/user settings.

Comment: @Mario I changed it. I used it because we can't know where the asker will put this PHP code and wanted to avoid any "Headers already sent" errors.

Comment: Well, that's a different story then. :) You could also assume there might have been a previous line where `Location` has been set as well.